# Looping object inside a table cell and create a unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have this table that has a column in which the cell may or may not contain a value, but when it does, it is in a JSON format; otherwise it will be empty (null).

```
<table>

<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Barley</td>
  <td>AK, AZ</td>
  <td class="fpdCell">[{"date":"06/01/2016","error":"Double/Triple cropping","id":2},{"date":"06/07/2016","error":"Lack of Planting Dates Established","id":2}]</td>
  <td>null</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Barley</td>
  <td>AK, AZ, AR</td>
  <td class="fpdCell">[{"date":"06/04/2016","error":"No Error Found","id":3},{"date":"06/27/2016","error":"Lack of Planting Dates Established","id":3},{"date":"06/28/2016","error":"Weather Patterns","id":3}]</td>
  <td>null</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Burley Tobacco</td>
  <td>null</td>
  <td class="fpdCell">null</td>
  <td>null</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Fire Cured Tobbacco</td>
  <td>null</td>
  <td class="fpdCell">null</td>
  <td>null</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Flue Cured Tobacco</td>
  <td>null</td>
  <td class="fpdCell">null</td>
  <td>null</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Oats</td>
  <td>null</td>
  <td class="fpdCell">null</td>
  <td>null</td>
</tr>
```

What I need to do is to loop through each of the cells with the `fpdCell` class, loop the object inside of each of those cell, create a list and add them as list element.

This is as far as I was able to get. I really don't know how to move forward from here.

```
var theCells = $('.fpdCell');
$.each(theCells, function(index, value) {

var cellValues = $.parseJSON(value.textContent);

if (cellValues != 'null') {
   console.log(cellValues);
   value.textContent = '';
   $(value).append('<ul class="list-group ul'+index+'"></ul>')

  //then add <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>

 //Not working------------------
 /*
   for (var u = 0; u < cellValues. length; u++) {
  $('ul' + index).append('<li class="list-group-item">'+cellValues[u].date+'</li>');
  console.log(cellValues[u].date);
}

 */
   }
 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you just need two loops, one to go through the `.fpdCell` elements, the other to go through the parsed JSON and build the HTML of the `ul`. Try this:

```
$('.fpdCell').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this), html = '';
    $.each(JSON.parse($el.text()), function(i, obj) {
        html += '<li class="list-group-item">' + obj.date + '</li>';
    })
    $el.append('<ul>' + html + '</ul>');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hjjf8gbo/)

Comment: Thanks. This was a tough decision, all answers provided worked one way or another. The only thing I add to your answer was a `$el.text('')` to empty to cell before inserting the list elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
var theCells = $('.fpdCell');
$.each(theCells, function() {

   var cellValues = $.parseJSON($(this).text());

   if (cellValues != 'null') {
      console.log(cellValues);
      $(this).html("");

      var list = '<ul class="list-group ul'+index+'">';

      for (var u = 0; u < cellValues.length; u++) {
          list+='<li class="list-group-item">'+cellValues[u].date+'</li>';
          console.log(cellValues[u].date);
      }

   if(cellValues.length>0)
      list+="</ul>";

    $(this).append(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The objects in the `fpdcell` columns are array objects which you may have missed in your logic.

One more thing, may be a typo, but, you missed the `.` in the commented code to append list items to the `ul` :)

Here is a solution which loops through the array and then loops through the individual elements in each array element to create a linear list.

```
var theCells = $('.fpdCell');
$.each(theCells, function(index, value) {
  var cellValues = JSON.parse(value.textContent);
  if (cellValues != 'null') {
    $(value).html('<ul class="list-group ul'+index+'"></ul>');
    $.each(cellValues, function(cellValueIndex, cellValue){
        for (var prop in cellValue) {
        $('.ul'+index).append('<li class="list-group-item">'+ cellValue[prop] +'</li>');
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(value).html('');
  }
});
```

This may not be the exact solution to what you are looking for but, should help you along the line you would want to go. Happy coding.

Here is a fiddle with the solution [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neildcruz19/1s555koy/6/)